# extract all decimal value from a string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to extract all decimal values from a string:

```
'1.1aa'        = 1.1,
'-1.1al3'      = -1.13,
' -'           = 0
'21d.2 d .3-d' = 21.23
```

What will be the query to extract this output?

```
   DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(100)='-c 43.f4gh57t';
   While (PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', @Col) > 0)
   begin
      SET @Col = STUFF(@Col, PATINDEX('%[^-0-9.]%', @Col), 1, '');
   end
      SELECT  CAST(@Col AS DECIMAL(18, 2));
```

I have written this query but it is not working with these values:

```
 ' -', 
'21d.2 d .3-d'
```

Comment: Please define "decimal value".  Show examples of sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(100)= '--A12345-..6789-.';
While (PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', @Col) > 0)
begin
  SET @Col = STUFF(@Col, PATINDEX('%[^-0-9.]%', @Col), 1, '');
end

--remove all hyphens but keep the first one (if first char with numbers following) 
select @Col = case when @Col like '-%[0-9]%' then '-' else '' end + replace(@Col, '-', '')
where @Col like '%-%';

--remove all dots but keep the first one (if followed by numbers) 
select @Col = stuff(replace(@Col, '.', '')+' ', charindex('.', @Col), 0, case when @Col like '%.%[0-9]%' then '.' else '' end)
where @Col like '%.%';

select @col as _col;
SELECT CAST(case when @col = '' then '0' else @col end AS DECIMAL(20,10)) as _decimal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Tally, though if you have multiple `'.'` characters or a `'-'` in the middle of the string it will fail on conversion:

```sql
DECLARE @Value varchar(100) = '-c 43.f4gh57t';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (LEN(@Value))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2),
Chars AS(
    SELECT T.I,
           SUBSTRING(@Value,T.I,1) AS C
    FROM Tally T)
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(decimal(25,10),STRING_AGG(C.C,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.I)) AS Number
FROM Chars C
WHERE C.C LIKE '[0-9.-]';
```

If you're using an older version of SQL Server, you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) technique instead of `STRING_AGG`.

---

Version 2: This should eliminate the errors I describe above:

```sql
DECLARE @Value varchar(100) = '-c 4-3.f4gh.57t';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (LEN(@Value))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2),
Chars AS(
    SELECT T.I,
           SUBSTRING(@Value,T.I,1) AS C
    FROM Tally T),
RNs AS(
    SELECT C.C,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C.I) AS RN,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.C ORDER BY C.I) AS cRN
    FROM Chars C
    WHERE C.C LIKE '[0-9.-]')
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(decimal(25,10),STRING_AGG(V.C,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY R.RN)) AS Number
FROM RNs R
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE R.C WHEN '-' THEN CASE R.RN WHEN 1 THEN R.C END
                                  WHEN '.' THEN CASE R.cRN WHEN 1 THEN R.C END
                                  ELSE R.C
                         END))V(C);
```